# Issue in handsontable. If i begin correcting my error cells or update a new cell, cell highlights disappear

Tags: javascript, handsontable

If i begin correcting my error cells or update a new cell, cell highlights disappear.The issue exists even if I scroll vertically.[Attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et9UX.png)

Comment: Can you add an example ?

Comment: attached screenshot.

Comment: How can you highlight your cell, attach code please ;)

Comment: By adding 'htInvalid' class of handsontable to the error cell.

Comment: This is custom validation code

Comment: You have already ask this question yesterday and delete your question, why ? I have already answer you.

Comment: Are you using the documentation ? https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.7.4/demo-data-validation.html

Comment: My requirement is I need to highlight the error cell. When user updates the cell all other highlights disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply to each cell you want to validate this validator :

```
requiredFieldValidator = function (value, callback) {
    if (!value) {
        //addErrorDiv(myMessageDiv, myErrorMessages.required_field); 
        callback(false);
    } else {
        callback(true);
    }
};
```

Like this :

```
columns: [
    {data: 'firstName', validator: 'requiredFieldValidator'},
    {data: 'lastName', validator: 'requiredFieldValidator'},
]
```

Example : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld1gorLx/)

Comment: I can't do anything more for you if you don't show me your code, as you can see it works in JSFiddle.

Comment: I have updated my example please check and tell me if it's correct ;)

Comment: The problem is it should not validate for all rows

Comment: There can be some rows left blank. In that case it should not validate

Comment: Can you want to say all columns ? It's because the first column hasn't got a validator just add `validator: requiredFieldValidator, allowInvalid: true` to column setting ;)

Comment: not columns. rows. based on this condition.                                                if (!hot.isEmptyRow(aRowIndex))

Comment: Oh sorry, you want to not validate the row if it is blank ?

Comment: I have updated my example, i hope i undestand now :)

Comment: wil check your example now.

Comment: could you please give me your personal email id? So that i will share my complete code

Comment: What do you need ? I am doing an example just apply it to your code ;) or do an JSFiddle with your custom code ;)

Comment: i have a question. Is it possible to have more than one custom validator in validator member.

Comment: You can apply different validator for each column (in column settings) but no more one validator for each one column. but you can create one validator with multiple conditions inside ;)

Comment: Assume if i have 1000 rows in my handsontable. I am copying some rows from an excel sheet, it is taking more time to copy. It is because of the callback?

Comment: Try to comment validator and see, but i think it that :/

Comment: after commenting it is copied fast.

Comment: i need to perform two validations for a particular column. The column is a dropdown. 1. Required Field validation 2. If i enter any other value, apart from source of dropdown the cell should be highlighted

Comment: So in the column settings put a `allowInvalid: false`.

Comment: Yes. I tried. But what actually happening is the cell highlight disappears for invalid country.If i enter something which is not available from dropdown cell should be highlighted.

Comment: cell is getting highlighted for required field but not happening for invalid country

Comment: I have updated my example with dropdown, you have to add a condition in the validator.

Comment: I checked your example. If i choose value from drop down (eg: Patrick - which is available in source) and clicked on submit. Highlight doesn't disappear

Comment: Oh sorry i forget `(` :/ try again ;)

Comment: Just change with this : `!($.inArray(value, hot.getSettings().columns[this.col].source) == -1));`

Comment: like this i have many validations for particular column. That is why i asked your personal email id. so that i can share my code. :)

Comment: Sorry but i am not going to do your work ;) you have all keys in your hands to do a good work, good luck ;) Regards

Comment: Thank you so much for the help you made. Can you just show me with 2 validation errors. Errors should contain "Please choose value from drop down only" if the value does not match the source. And, "First and last name are required" if either first or last name is null

Comment: You're welcome ;) I have updated my example with custom error, it is not the best solution but it's quick :)

Comment: Thanks you so much for the help you made. Because of your examples, apart from yours,  i was able to fix all other validations. Once again thanks a lot.

Comment: As you said, I have all keys in my hands to continue good work. Thanks!!